# ImportError: No module named _vectorized

Tags: python, shapely

I m using Shapely package for my Python and Plone Project.  In packages.cfg file under   eggs section i use shapely to download like this

```
[eggs]
main =
      Shapely
```

during bin/buildout i see that there is a problem in shapely.vectorized. The error seems to be like this

```
Numpy or Cython not available, shapely.vectorized submodule not being built.
```

I created unit tests for my python functions. When i run my file i get error. The Trace back of the Error is

```
Module: shapely.tests.test_validation

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nirmalsudhir/zope/myProject/eggs/Shapely-1.3.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/shapely 
      /tests/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import test_doctests, test_prepared, test_equality, test_geomseq, \
File "/home/nirmalsudhir/zope/myProject/eggs/Shapely-1.3.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/shapely
      /tests/test_vectorized.py", line 3, in <module>
from shapely.vectorized import contains, touches
File "/home/nirmalsudhir/zope/myProject/eggs/Shapely-1.3.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/shapely
      /vectorized/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from ._vectorized import contains, touches
ImportError: No module named _vectorized
```

`shapely/tests/__init__.py` :

```
import sys
from shapely.geos import geos_version_string, lgeos, WKTWriter
from shapely import speedups

try:
    import numpy
    numpy_version = numpy.version.version
except ImportError:
    numpy = False
    numpy_version = 'not available'


if lgeos.geos_version >= (3, 3, 0):
    WKTWriter.defaults = {}

if sys.version_info[0:2] <= (2, 6):
   import unittest2 as unittest
else:
import unittest

from . import test_doctests, test_prepared, test_equality, test_geomseq // I get error here
```

`shapely/tests/test_vectorized.py:`

```
from . import unittest, numpy
from shapely.geometry import Point, box, MultiPolygon
from shapely.vectorized import contains, touches
```

`shapely/vectorized/__init__.py:`

```
from ._vectorized import contains, touches
```

I dont know Whats wrong with the vectorized. Can anyone help.

Comment: @@BartoszKP: I download the shapely package in to my project during the bin/buildout by mentioning **[eggs] main = Shapely**  in packages.cfg

Comment: @@BartoszKP: Rename Project? my project name is myProject.. What is the use of changing project name. I dont get you

Comment: @@BartoszKP: Ah, its my mistake. But thanks for reply

Comment: "from ." is not needed... Just leave it out

Comment: your question is lacking a lot of information about your environment - are you running this in a virtualenv or using system packages? have you tried installing numpy and/or cython?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install Numpy or Cython

In my case I was using a virtualenv so I simply did

```
pip install numpy cython
```

Your question is lacking information about your environment so I cannot say if this will work for you.

Comment: If you got the 'No module named _vectorized' then you probably also need to uninstall Shapely and reinstall it after numpy and cython are installed.